# Does Phantomjs support CSS3 Columns for HTML to PDF conversion?

Tags: css, phantomjs

I'm trying to convert a html page to PDF. The conversion works fine with PhantomJS, however, phantomjs does not seem to support [CSS3 columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp).

The command I'm running (html->pdf)

```
phantomjs.exe examples/rasterize.js http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-columns.php sample.pdf
```

The resulting PDF does not honour the CSS columns style, displaying a vertical list of items instead.

However, running the following command to convert **html->image does honour the CSS3 Columns style**:

```
phantomjs.exe examples/rasterize.js http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-columns.php sample.png
```

Can someone please confirm that this is expected behaviour?

BTW, I've tried using [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) but this [does/will not be supporting CSS Columns](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=218).

Many Thanks

Comment: Curious if you ever found anything that supported columns. I'm bumping into similar issues, and while wkhtmltopdf has done very well, I'd still like to have column support.

Comment: @Dante617 Nope, nothing that is open-source supports CSS3 columns. I tried Phantom JS and wkhtmltopdf to no avail. Both generators are very good libraries. Phantom is slightly better in terms of speed.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, Phantom JS was what I ended up going with as well, since it had good support for float, and I just used that to mimic columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the webkit version on which PhantomJs relies probably is not implementing CSS3 columns, although the major webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) both do.  This link

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Supported-Web-Standards

and this link

http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitFeatures22

will shed as much as light as there is on this topic, AFAIK.

Comment: I came to this very conclusion to. Many Thanks.

Comment: Vote for the issue here:  https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11821.  The "work around" is to convert to an image first

Answer (score 2):

I've come to the same conclusion as @Stolli. But as a work around, I did do the following:

Use CSS3 columns and convert the html to an image using wkhtmltoimage which ships with the wkhtmltopdf library. This will maintain the CSS3 column structure.

Then embed the generated image in a html string like:
`<html><img src='path/to/my/file'/></html>` and convert to PDF using wkhtmltopdf.

Obviously, there are allot of dependencies here, so it is not ideal for a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe it does to this day but an alternative is to use https://github.com/peterdemartini/html5-to-pdf which uses Nightmare browser instead of phantom and supports CSS columns, I just tried it out.